# Why does my GNU make skip making an object file (%.o) when building an %.s (assembler) program?

Tags: gcc, assembly, makefile, gnu-make

I am using implicit rules only - removing the makefile altogether for a minimal test case. I have an empty (no problem for GNU assembler) `program.s` file. Executing:

```
make program
```

Gives me following output from make:

```
cc    program.s   -o program
```

(and of course the expected errors, which here is of no importance for the question: since my assembler source file is empty, there is no "_start" and all kinds of linking fails.)

I wonder, why does make choose to attempt to build the program in one go? As opposed to first using `as program.s ...` and then `ld program.o ...`? Is this because it considers the object file unnecessary in my scenario here?

If I do `make program.o`, then `as program.as ...` is invoked, producing my `program.o` as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make will always choose [one-step implicit rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html) in preference to multi-step implicit rules, to get the same result.  In this case, make contains built-in rules that create an executable both from an object file, but also directly from various source files including assembly:

```
%: %.s
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.s) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Since this is shorter than first building the `.o` then building the executable from the `.o`, and since your makefile doesn't say you want the `.o`, make uses the shortest set of steps.

Comment: Thank you, mr. mad scientist. I have just found the implicit rule in question by doing a `make -pn program`.

Comment: The simplest way to see the entire built-in rule database is to run `make -p -f /dev/null`